keep getting 401 while trying to implement auth0 with nestjs
Im trying to setup auth0 with nestjs without any success.
my stack is: react and nestjs.
So i managed to login from the frontend and get the access token.
In my nestjs application i have the following files:
auth.module
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forFeature(authConfig),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
  ],
  providers: [JwtStrategy],
  exports: [PassportModule, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}

jwt.strategy.ts
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy as BaseStrategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';

import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(BaseStrategy) {
  constructor(configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${configService.get<string>(
          'auth.domain',
        )}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: configService.get<string>('auth.audience'),
      issuer: `https://${configService.get<string>('auth.domain')}/`,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: JwtPayload): JwtPayload {
    console.log('Payload received:', payload);
    const minimumScope = ['openid', 'profile', 'email'];

    if (
      payload?.scope
        ?.split(' ')
        .filter((scope) => minimumScope.indexOf(scope) > -1).length !== 3
    ) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'JWT does not possess the required scope (`openid profile email`).',
      );
    }

    return payload;
  }
}

app.controller.ts
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  @Get('/ping')
  ping(): string {
    return 'pong';
  }

i configured the auth0 clientId in the frontend and created an API for the backend and to get the audience.
so in my config i have this:
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';

export default registerAs('auth', () => ({
  domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
  clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
}));

for some reason i keep getting 401 Unauthorized. I'm trying to fix this for an hours without any success.

Start investigating WHY you get 401, is it a UnauthorizedException from nestjs? Is the JWT signature not accepted? Missing scopes? Any logs from Auth0?
